# Array get key with the similar value

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [F] => 09:00 - 18:00
    [M] => 09:00 - 18:00
    [Th] => 09:00 - 18:00
    [W] => 09:00 - 18:00
    [T] => 09:00 - 18:00
    [Su] => RD
    [Sa] => RD
)
```

and I want to produce this output:

MTWThF 9:00 - 18:00 SaSu RD

this is my code:

```
array_s=array(
        F => 09:00 - 18:00
        M => 09:00 - 18:00
        Th => 09:00 - 18:00
        W => 09:00 - 18:00
        T => 09:00 - 18:00
        Su => RD
        Sa => RD
)

  asort($array_s);
  $temp_s = '';
  foreach($array_s as $key => $value){
    if($temp_s == null){
      $temp_s = $value; //first array
      $temp_day = $key;
      $res_day .= $temp_day;
    }else{
      if($value == $temp_s){
        $res_day .= $key;
      }else{
      echo $res_day ." ". $temp_s;
        $res_day = null;
        $temp_s = $value;
        $temp_day = $key;
        $res_day .= $temp_day;
      }
    }
```

but the output is this:

FMThWT 09:00 - 18:00
May be I did something wrong but I dont know how to fix error. thanks

Comment: Show us your code? Won't be able to help without it.

Comment: yes @sectus.. the input is the schedule time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do something like this. Here's an example:

```
foreach(array_values($array_s) as $value) {
    foreach($array_s as $key => $current) {
        if($value != $current)
            continue;
        if(!array_key_exists($value, $output))
            $output[$value] = array();
        if(!in_array($key, $output[$value]))
            $output[$value][] = $key;
    }
}
```

[This gives you a structured array like this:](https://eval.in/78516)

```
Array
(
    [09:00 - 18:00] => Array
        (
            [0] => F
            [1] => M
            [2] => Th
            [3] => W
            [4] => T
        )

    [RD] => Array
        (
            [0] => Su
            [1] => Sa
        )

)
```

Then, you can output it like this:

```
foreach($output as $key => $current) {
    echo implode('', $current) . ' ' . $key . ' ';
}
```

Weird way to output data, but that'll give you:

```
FMThWT 09:00 - 18:00 SuSa RD
```

... it's not in the order you want, but the best way to achieve that order is to fix it where you **create** the array (as it's obviously a date related thing) - harder to sort that you've created it like that than it is to sort it at the beginning. If you decide that you'd rather sort it here, [have a look at this post and use his example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678344/2812842)

**Output demo:** https://eval.in/78517

> Documentation

- [array_values()](http://www.php.net/array_values)
- [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/array_key_exists)
- [in_array()](http://www.php.net/in_array)
- [implode()](http://php.net/function.implode)

Answer (score 0):

After the **foreach** is done, you need to **echo** what's left:

```
array_s=array(
        F => 09:00 - 18:00
        M => 09:00 - 18:00
        Th => 09:00 - 18:00
        W => 09:00 - 18:00
        T => 09:00 - 18:00
        Su => RD
        Sa => RD
)

  asort($array_s);
  $temp_s = '';
  foreach($array_s as $key => $value){
    if($temp_s == null){
      $temp_s = $value; //first array
      $temp_day = $key;
      $res_day .= $temp_day;
    }else{
      if($value == $temp_s){
        $res_day .= $key;
      }else{
      echo $res_day ." ". $temp_s;
        $res_day = null;
        $temp_s = $value;
        $temp_day = $key;
        $res_day .= $temp_day;
      }
    }
  }
  echo $res_day ." ". $temp_s;
```